# mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty) on Jammy Jellyfish

Tags: 22.04, lts, bug-reporting

I had recently installed Ubuntu 22.04. Everything was fine initially. But I don't remember if I had done some updates, now I am unable to boot into the system. Please help me to fix this bug.[image]

Comment: See these: mtd device must be supplied
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2476796&page=3 & 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1981622 Most find it does boot after complaining. Why are you at root, not your user?

Comment: "Not your user?" I didn't get it. I had tried all those links the problem still persist.

Comment: That you are at root@xxx# not $USER@xxx$ means you have logged into root. That is not recommended. The use of sudo for admin purposed is the standard method with Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't know how it logged into Root. After starting it just display that screen